# Italic TextView with wrap_contents seems to clip the text at right edge

Tags: android, textview, italic

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/prodLbl"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="30dip"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="Magnifico"
    />
```

Seems to clip few pixels from the rightmost character, at least on 480x800 emulator or Nexus One.

To me it looks like a bug, but I'm just an Android beginner.
I tried to add margins to left and right, but it still kept on clipping.
In the end my hack around it was to add a single space on both sides of the text.
Any other solutions?

Comment: Can you post an image of what you are seeing?

Comment: http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/2865/textclip.png see the rightmost 'o'

Comment: You mentioned margins, did you mean padding?

Comment: This problem is also bugging me

Comment: it's insane, that this still happens in 2023 ‍♂️

Answer (score 29):

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"` , gives you a rectangle for wrapped content rendering.
All will work well for normal text (non-italic).

Once you have `italic` text enabled, the wrapped text will try to fit into the rectangle and hence the rightmost character will be cut off unless its un-cut-able (such as `.`, `)`, `1`, etc.)

Solution as suggested is to have a space at the end of the text (or anything better ??)

***PS:*** This applies to `android:gravity="right"` too because the text will be pushed to the rightmost. If we have `italic` text, we face the same problem.

Comment: This is unbelievable ... Why, mister Android ? Tell me it's a bug and it's going to be fixed..

Comment: It will never be fixed. The question is from 2010 and here I am looking for a solution in 2022...

Comment: if you add space or any other characters, the space will increase according to the textview text size. if anyone increases the textsize dynamically, the space will also get increased.

Answer (score 29):

You could also use the [Unicode no-break space character](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/A0/index.htm) (\u00A0).

Comment: This doesn't work well with every language.

Answer (score 13):

I added `" \"` to end of all strings in my strings.xml. `\` is the escape character, so this way I could come over the issue, but this solution is nasty. Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the only workaround that works reliably. If you use resource strings the trailing space will get removed (why does it do that?) so that has no effect, but the slash takes care of that.

Comment: I don't think that's an escape character for XML, at least I didn't see it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

But this definitely worked for me! I wonder why.

Answer (score 8):

Just add an extra space to the end of the text. In XML, you will have to add `\u0020` to the end as otherwise XML ignores whitespace at the beginning/end by default.

Comment: Had the same issue using setTextSkewX (which is another way to italicize text). This fixed that issue as well.

Answer (score 8):

Found another solution (tested on 4.1.2 and 4.3 while using `wrap_content`). If you extend `TextView` or `EditText` class you can override `onMeasure` method this way:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    final int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    final float tenPercentOfMeasuredWidth = measuredWidth * 0.1f;
    final int newWidth = measuredWidth + (int) tenPercentOfMeasuredWidth;

    setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, getMeasuredHeight());
}
```

Comment: in 2022 this answer still works like a charm.. Thanks for sharing.  is there any chance of that this  impacting app performance?

Answer (score 6):

You can add a HAIR SPACE to your string

```
<string name="hair_space">&#x200A;</string>

String hairSpace = getContext().getString(R.string.hair_space);
textView.setText(hairSpace + originalString + hairSpace)
```

Comment: this works well, thanks ! I hate these hacks that Google forces us to do !

Answer (score 2):

This applies to fixed-width TextViews also, not just "wrap_content".  I'm not sure if the issue is version-specific as some commenters have alluded to.  I see the issue on all Honeycomb versions.  From what I've seen the issue does not go away by setting margin, padding, using a fixed-width, or a true-italic custom typeface.

Comment: It does go away by setting true-italic typeface in XML now. Thanks for the hint. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source I found out that setting a shadow extends the clip rectangle.

A trick is to set an invisible shadow just beyond the character.

For example:

```
android:shadowRadius="2"
android:shadowDx="2"
android:shadowColor="#00000000"
```

I think this solution is better as it will not extend the width of the `TextView` which may happen when adding an extra character (which is more apparent with a background).

Comment: Edited: Remove the dips

Answer (score 2):

**A proper and clean solution:**

Use an italic custom font instead of setting textStyle='italic'
For example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:text="yolO"
            app:fontFamily="@font/roboto_italic"/>
```

I haven't tried it on regular TextView but from my observations, the problem is with textStyle='italic'.

**Works without any hack!**

**Here's a proof of blaming textStyle attribute:**

I made a custom fontFamily and defined typeface for normal, bold and italic

*res/font/app_font_family.xml*

```
<font-family xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/roboto_regular"/>
    <font app:fontStyle="italic" app:fontWeight="400" app:font="@font/roboto_italic" />
    <font app:fontStyle="normal" app:fontWeight="700" app:font="@font/roboto_medium"/>
</font-family>
```

Now when I use this fontFamily and apply textStyle='italic', the rightmost character is still clipped.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:text="yolO"
            app:fontFamily="@font/app_font_family"
            android:textStyle='italic' />
```

This is on Api 23 with support library 28.0.0 and Android Studio 3.2

Comment: The best solutions

Comment: Doesn't work for me, it's still cut off even with the roboto-italic font in my assets

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution: Format textview and measure. After that set width of textview with 1 pixel add to the width measured.

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this);
textView.setText("Text blah blah");
textView.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC)
textView.measure(MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(textView.getMeasuredWidth() + 1, 
                                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Working for me. Hope these help.

Comment: This is a proper solution instead of a hack

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue and used a non-breaking space entity via HTML:

```
textView.setText("Magnifico" + Html.fromHtml("&nbsp;");
```

Comment: fromHtml(String) is deprecated in API 24

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that if you apply italic programatically, it does content wrapping correctly. So set the typeface of the TextView manually, e.g. in kotlin:

```
textView.typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.DEFAULT, Typeface.ITALIC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'd generally prefer [sziraqui's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54033946/12121416) that suggests using a true italic font, these are not always available.
As the problem at hand is caused by the mismeasurement of the text's boundaries, I just set `android:layout_width="0dp"`, giving the TextView as much horizontal space as it needs. This might also not be ideal in all circumstances, but it's a simple and not too hackish solution for many situations.

Answer (score -3):

Add a 3dp padding to the right on your TextView. I tried with 1dp and 2dp, but 3dp seemed to do the trick fully.

`android:paddingRight="3dp"`

Comment: Padding doesnt seem to affect the text clip rect, at least not on 2.3.

Comment: Same for the title of an app (in my case ActionBarSherlock) which doesn't make it that simple to customize the title TextView. But thanks for trying.