# Android ActionBarSherlock Title Cropped

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, title, crop

Has anyone experience with a cropped title / label and ActionBarSherlock?

Using

```
<application
    android:name="WasserwegeApp"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme" >
```

and the string:

```
<string name="app_name">Wasserwege  </string>
```

I don't think the App-Theme has anything to do with it but this is what I use:

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/blue_light</item>
<item name="textColorPrimary">@color/blue_light</item>
<item name="android:textColor">@color/blue_light</item>
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.AppTheme.ActionBar</item>

<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>      

<item name="actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_divider</item>
<item name="android:actionBarDivider">@drawable/actionbar_divider</item>
</style>
```

It always looks like that:

[image]

And I even tried to fix this by adding a space behind the string but it doesn't work.
It looks like the *italic font style* is making it difficult.

Thanks for any help,

Tobias

Comment: Can you post some layout code?

Comment: Well, there is no real layout. I use ABS and there I'm using the given label="..." in the Manifest. But I will post a bit more.

Comment: Test with non-italic text. Or try to add right margin(right padding) to your label

Comment: The non-italic text works fine. Looks like the ActionBar doesn't compute the wider size. But how can I define the margin for the actionbar title?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, this isn't just an issue with ABS, but a problem with `TextView` (i.e., see [Italic TextView with wrap_contents seems to clip the text at right edge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353836/italic-textview-with-wrap-contents-seems-to-clip-the-text-at-right-edge)).

The solution is indeed to add a space to the end. If you're using XML, the space will be chopped off, so you will have to do something like this to force a whitespace:

```
<string name="app_name">Wasserwege\u0020\u0020</string>
```

Comment: Weird enough, it seems to work with that. Even though, adding a space directly didn't work...
Thank you anyway! :-)