# TextView not completely visible even in wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, textview

I have 2 text views in my layout with a different font and their height and width are set to wrap_content.
But still a small part of the text view is cut out and is not completely visible.

[image]

As seen in the image , S of mines and E of time is not completely visible.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#121212">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/activity_board_restart"
        android:layout_width="91dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/board"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/activity_board_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/activity_board_mines_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/smile" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_board_mines_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
        android:text="@string/mines"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_board_mines"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="@string/default_value"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_board_mines_label"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.514"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_board_mines_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/activity_board_mines_label" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/activity_board_time_label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/bangers"
        android:text="@string/time"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Chronometer
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/activity_board_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/activity_board_time_label"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_board_time_label" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/board"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/activity_board_restart"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.
PS . complete text is being shown when i am setting the width to match_constraint.

Comment: This has to do with the Android system for measurement and the fact that you're using a custom typeface. Try adding a space at the end of your text to provide extra room. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4353836/italic-textview-with-wrap-contents-seems-to-clip-the-text-at-right-edge

Comment: @BenP. post this as an answer . I will accept this answer. Thankyou :)